# How do I build a runtime version agnostic DLL in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

My product is a C++ library, which, on Windows, is distributed as a dll. It makes very little use of the c-runtime (basic iostream and that's it), so I'm sure that all recent versions of the CRT will be fine.

Since my client is supposed to build his application using my dll, I don't want to impose upon him any specific runtime version. I'd like my dll to bind to whatever runtime library version my client's app is using (and I can assume that he'll use dynamic linking for his CRT). After all, isn't that what dynamic linking is all about? Is that possible?

EDIT: linking the dll against the static runtime libs won't work either, because then the static runtime (from the dll) and the dynamic runtime (from the client's application) will be mixed, which is bad.

EDIT: What I'm mainly asking is how do I tell the runtime loader to link my dll against whatever CRT the application is linked with? Something with the manifest, perhaps?
More generally, my question is how to build a nicely-behaving dll, that's to be used by clients building they're own applications?

EDIT: Thanks to the advice in the answers, I've transferred all references to std classes into inlined functions in my headers, and linked my dll with the static runtime libraries. It now seems to work even in applications linked with different CRT versions.

Comment: Maybe, but my question stands. I certainly don't do anything fancy that might be broken in some version of the CRT.

Comment: You don't have to do something "fancy" in order to be coupled to a specific CRT.

Comment: C++ + DLLs == Pain. I strongly suggest exposing C-only interfaces between DLLs.

Comment: doesn't your DLL ever change? if yes you will still be dealing with versions regardless of what technology you choose. Using COM at least makes the version very clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no real way to ensure your DLL works with multiple runtimes -- any of the types that change between them can lead to incompatibilities.  For instance, the size of an object can change, or the location of members in them.  There is very little room in C++ for this kind of thing.

The best thing you can do is statically link to the runtime and ensure the exported API is limited to types strictly under your control -- no passing `std::string` to a function, no stdlib types as members, and don't `new` in one DLL and `delete` in another.  Don't mix inline and exported functions (including constructors/destructors) for the same object, because member order and padding might change between compilers.  The pimpl idiom might help here.

Comment: Would you say that this is the common practice for products delivered as dlls?

Comment: I don't know if it is "standard practise" (if any such animal really exists).  But it is certainly sound advise.  I go a step further in my DLLs and limit the functions to things that can be called using "C".

Comment: Many people avoid exporting runtime-portable C++ functions due to these complexities, but it's common practice among those that do.

Comment: A common way to get around this problem (in Windows) is to use COM. Of course, COM itself is a pain in the butt to produce and consume in C++, and versioning tends to be a big problem. The solution I prefer is not to use C++ :)

Answer (score 6):

If you expose any C++ objects across DLL boundaries then this is simply not possible.  What you can do (and we use a 3rd-party DLL that does this) is build your library in multiple configurations (32-bit/64-bit, debug/release, static/dynamic runtime, static/dynamic library) to satisfy as many people as possible.  This may be a bit tedious to setup at first, but once you have all the configurations setup it's just a matter of building them all.  Of course you also need to consider which runtime you are building against (vc8, vc9, vc10, etc), so if you want to cover all the bases you could have quite a lot of configurations.

Comment: why hate windows? It's innocent of any crimes in this thread.

Comment: Eh, maybe not. I just get the sense that the Windows CRT change versions and break compatibility more than, say, on linux. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: the windows C runtime is different and since there is exactly one per machine there are no issues. You have been discussing the MSVC runtime which is quite different.

Answer (score 4):

Linking your DLL against the static runtime libs should work, except that you must be very careful about memory management (e.g. whoever calls your DLL can't free() or delete[] anything allocated by your DLL) and you cannot exchange standard C data structures (e.g. FILE*). (Am I missing anything?)

Comment: Hmm, well that would be a problem. From the thrust of the answers so far, it seems that the answer is: "No, you can't do that. dlls and the applications using them should use the same CRT"

Comment: And, BTW, why would it be a problem to free() an object allocated by a different CRT? Does the Windows CRT change the way it stores the size information between versions?

Comment: Likely, all run time libraries end up calling the same basic win32 functions to allocate memory for a process.  The difference is that each run time library instance will keep "extra" book-keeping data associated with each object that is allocated (using new or malloc()).  If one DLL allocates memory using its own run time and the process deletes that memory using its own run-time,  the heaps of one or both are likely to become corrupt.  Final answer, don't mix them.

Comment: @pron: not only between versions, but also between configurations. Consider debug vs. release builds. So you can't mix these DLLs either. The best way, in my opinion, is that every object brings the means to destroy itself without having to rely on some external means. In the end this would mean a similar mechanism to interfaces in COM, which will die when their refcount drops to zero.

Comment: Different configurations may be the bigger problem. The CRT debug heap does a bunch of special bookkeeping (see http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html) which I would expect makes it incompatible with Release builds. Anyway, different CRT versions MIGHT use the same heap and same bookkeeping methods, but you can't rely on it (because MS feels free to change anything between versions, without necessarily documenting those changes.) So to find out if two versions are compatible you'd have to do some experiments. I haven't done such experiments personally.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using WinAPI calls for I/O and anything else that possibly relies on the runtime.

The most painful part is that you may have to override the global `new` and `delete` to use WinAPI functions exclusively because they are likely to use malloc/free internally. There are many other painful aspects to this, and my opinions is that it isn't worth the trouble. [Here](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/minexe) is an article that covers this topic.

Comment: The *funny* thing about this is that HeapAlloc and HeapFree (from kernel32.lib) are even slightly faster than the malloc/free implementations of the MSVCRT dlls.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's worth the trouble either, so let's assume I do need the CRT.

Comment: DLLs have a poor ABI compatibility. I think you can't ensure that it can use different runtimes. For example, Qt has different DLLs for MSVC and Mingw.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to expose your objects in a runtime neutral way then I can't see any solution other than COM.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a huge difference between the C-runtime and the C++-runtime. If you where to use msvcrt.dll, which in recent years became "knighted" as a true system DLL, you could rely on its existence on XP onwards (though for Windows 2000 you would need some redistributable for the version 6 of msvcrt.dll). You can make use of msvcrt.dll by compiling your code with the compiler from the latest WDKs (Windows Driver Kits). Even though this is user-mode code, this is a viable and good method to compiler it.

IOStreams, however, require the C++-runtime. And that complicates things a lot.

> EDIT: linking the dll against the
>   static runtime libs won't work either,
>   because then the static runtime (from
>   the dll) and the dynamic runtime (from
>   the client's application) will be
>   mixed, which is bad.

Well, if you *mix* code in such a way, you have something wrong in your design. You would have similar problems when running a debug build of your DLL with a release build of the other code or vice versa.

I can only recommend that you either make direct use of COM, or - if that's too big - try to emulate some ideas of COM. The most important one would be that you have a factory function and that there is an (class) interface declared (and gets never changed) between those two pieces of code (i.e. the DLL and its caller). The factory function would return an instance of the class and the class would manage its lifetime itself (which implies that all code for allocation and deallocation would reside in the same entity, i.e. your DLL). The lifetime management would then be exposed via `addref` and `release` member functions. `IUnknown` could be the basis for this interface of yours without relying on other parts of the actual COM.

> EDIT: What I'm mainly asking is how do
>   I tell the runtime loader to link my
>   dll against whatever CRT the
>   application is linked with? Something
>   with the manifest, perhaps? More
>   generally, my question is how to build
>   a nicely-behaving dll, that's to be
>   used by clients building they're own
>   applications?

Not easy at all. Even if you had all the versions of VS installed, you'd have to script your way out of this dilemma to pick the right version.

Answer (score 0):

Your dll is linked against the c-runtime it was compiled with. Your application will always use this runtime. Anyone who links to your dll uses their c-runtime. So there won't be any problem with this.

Comment: So, you mean that the final application would be possibly linked with 2 different runtimes and that's fine?

Comment: That may not be "fine".  Depends on your usage.

Comment: If for example you `new` something using one CRT and `delete` it using another, that may be very not "fine".

Comment: OK, so what should I do if I want to give my client a nicely-behaving dll?

Answer (score 0):

If you use C++, it seems to be impossible to cross runtime boundaries unless you limit yourself on what can be exposed. As mentioned earlier, std:: objects do not work (std::string for instance).

Here is a small example that will cause a crash:

class Base
   {
   public:
     virtual ~Base()
     {
     }
   };

class ClassInDll : public Base
{
public:
   __declspec( dllexport ) ClassInDll( int arg );
   __declspec( dllexport ) ~ClassInDll();

private:
    int _arg;
};

If this class is compiled into a VS2008 release mode DLL and one builds a .exe in VS2008 debug mode doing the following:

ClassInDll* c = new ClassInDll( 1 );
delete c;

the "delete c" statement causes a crash.
It has to do with the fact that ClassInDll has a virtual destructor.

Comment: @David Feurle: The application will NOT use the same runtime as the DLL, that is the heart of the problem.