# What is the best way to insulate new C++ code from an older (binary) component using a different CRT?

Tags: c++, com, msvcrt

I work on a large codebase for a Windows desktop application written in C++.

Many years ago, my company paid license fee to a much bigger company for use of a component which is incorporated into our software and provides a critical service. The component is a binary blob with some header files and was compiled using the VS2008 runtime.

Currently, as a result, the entire application is now dependent on the VS2008 runtime. We are unable to upgrade to modern C++, or newer versions of the libraries we use (we're stuck on Qt4 rather than Qt5 for example).
For various reasons, there is little to no chance of said company ever providing updated blobs and, whilst we are planning to write our own replacement, it will take a lot of time.

In the meantime, I would like to be able to wrap this component up in some way and insulate it, so we can upgrade the rest of our code to a later runtime, and communicate with it using JSON or similar. *Potentially* at some point in the future we may replace the component with something of our own (or something open source) not written in C++ at all.

I can think of a number of ways of doing this, but I'm not sure which is best, and which will give us the most flexibility going forward. Reading about COM, it seems that this was the very purpose it was created for, but I don't know if COM is still actively developed and supported, and if it will tie us forevermore to the Windows ecosystem. DCOM is the non-Windows version but if anything that seems even more abandoned.

I'm interested in any suggestions as to the best way to proceed. Thus far my ideas are:

- *Very carefully* design a DLL (which may or may not work, I can't tell from [How do I build a runtime version agnostic DLL in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205960/how-do-i-build-a-runtime-version-agnostic-dll-in-c), but it looks like it will be suboptimal)
- Use COM (see reservations above)
- Run as a separate process, and pipe data via cin and cout (restricts to text data and might be slow?)
- Run as a separate process, and run a simple client/server relationship (seems heavyweight)

Comment: How would it be a problem to be bound to Windows, if you're currently bound to VS2008? Being bound to VS2008 already implies being bound to Windows.

Comment: You've already got the options, which one is best for you is difficult to say without a [mre]

Comment: If the said library is build dynamically with CRT, the only option you have is inter-process communication. The nature of such communication would be defined by actual functionality provided by the lib.

Comment: It's not a massive problem, but other than the problematic component, everything else is C++ and Qt and so pretty much OS-independent. My natural instinct is to avoid platform dependence as much as possible.

Comment: Host the dll in another process seems clean. But you will loose performance. The COM parts that you need is very far from being abandoned. COM is everywhere in Windows, also in new WinRT. It even allows you to do x64-x86 ipc. I would choose COM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

COM is not actively developed mostly because it's finished. It is actively supported, though. For instance, when Windows went 64 bit, COM was also ported to 64 bits. It gets security updates when necessary.

DCOM is the *distributed* variant of COM. I wouldn't bother; you just design everything to run on one PC using a single user account. That's already how your app runs anyway.

VS2008 is entirely happy to use `BSTR` strings over (D)COM, and VS2019 has a convenient `_bstr_t` wrapper for that. (I don't remember if VS2008 already had `_bstr_t`).

You typically don't need to use all of the features of COM. COM was designed as an interop platform between many varied applications, but you have two parts of a codebase written by the same developers, which only need to work with each other. There's no need to dynamically discover COM interfaces etcetera. You can just share a `.h` file with the interface definitions.

Comment: > COM is not actively developed mostly because it's finished. It is actively supported, though
I hadn't looked at it this way. This is very clarifying, and COM does seem to be the technology most suited to what I want to do.

It seems like the right way to go: especially since you point out we don't need to use some of the more heavyweight stuff. Thank you for your answer.

Now to find a decent "Getting Started with COM" resource that is up-to-date :)